# Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (4)

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap, geom-text

I am working with `ggmap`. the goal is to plot coordinate points on the map and label the points with their names. I have data frame with name, longitude and latitude.

The data looks like:

```
df <- structure(list(Station.Area = c("Balbriggan", "Blanchardstown", 
"Dolphins Barn", "Donnybrook", "Dun Laoghaire", "Finglas"), Latitude = c(53.608319, 
53.386813, 53.333532, 53.319259, 53.294396, 53.390325), Longitude = c(-6.18208, 
-6.377197, -6.29146, -6.232017, -6.133867, -6.298401)), .Names =c("Station.Area","Latitude", "Longitude"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

The code I wrote is as below:

```
library(ggmap)
library(ggplot2)

dub_map <- get_map(location = "Dublin", zoom = "auto", scale="auto", crop = TRUE, maptype = "hybrid")

ggmap(dub_map) +`
    geom_point(data = df, aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude, 
              fill = "green", alpha =` `0.8, size = 5, shape = 21)) +`
guides(fill=FALSE, alpha=FALSE, size=FALSE)+
geom_text(label=df$Station.Area)+
scale_shape_identity()
```

But i am getting

> Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (4): label

I have tried to put various aesthetics in `geom_text` like size,color,x & Y but it still gives out same error.

Am i doing it correctly for my goal? Please help.

Getting this without geom_text now I just want to label the points

[image]

Comment: I wonder if you want `geom_text(aes(label=Station.Area))` . Also dont  size, alpha etc like that in the `aes` - do it outside

Comment: yea i want to use the same but when i run the code without df$ it doesn't recognize the column.

Comment: okay, can you share some of your data?? If so, can you edit your question with th results of `dput(head(df))`

Comment: Station Area Latitude Longitude
Balbriggan 53.608319 -6.18208
Blanchardstown 53.386813 -6.377197
Dolphins Barn 53.333532 -6.29146
Donnybrook 53.319259 -6.232017
Dun Laoghaire 53.294396 -6.133867
Finglas 53.390325 -6.298401
Kilbarrack 53.383747 -6.15254
North Strand 53.358192 -6.240886
Phibsborough 53.359906 -6.2724
Rathfarnham 53.300498 -6.283854
Skerries 53.580552 -6.107878
Swords 53.455747 -6.219741
Tallaght 53.288804 -6.355706
Tara St 53.3473         -6.2549

Comment: Sorry the data was in excel i just copied and pasted. Basically there are three columns Station Area, Latitude and Longitude. So if you can please read it like that

Comment: Btw I didn't understand " can you edit your question with th results of dput(head(df))".

Comment: by edit, I mean you click the edit button at the bottom left of your question, and paste in the results of `dput(head(df))` (which you type into your R session)

Comment: that worked!!! thanks!!!

Comment: Actually, this may be better... `ggmap(dub_map, base_layer = ggplot(data=df, aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude, 
                                       label=Station.Area))) +
      geom_point(fill = "green", alpha =0.8, size = 5, shape = 21) +
guides(fill=FALSE, alpha=FALSE, size=FALSE) +
geom_text() + 
scale_shape_identity()` to save passing the data to each geom

Comment: perfect!! thanks again!!

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of things not quite right in your code.

For the `geom_point` you only want the `x` and `y` in your `aes`. The other arguments
should be outside, giving

```
geom_point(data = df, aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude), 
                  fill = "green", alpha =0.8, size = 5, shape = 21)
```

Also the `label` for the `geom_text` should be inside `aes`. However, 
as there is no `data`, `x` or `y` at a higher level, then `geom_text`
will not find the label variable or the positions of where to place the labels. So you also need to include these in the call

```
geom_text(data=df, aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude, label=Station.Area))
```

However, you can omit some of this repetition by using the `base_layer` argument
  of `ggmap`:

```
ggmap(dub_map, 
      base_layer = ggplot(data=df, aes(x = Longitude, 
                                       y = Latitude, 
                                       label=Station.Area))) +
      geom_point(fill = "green", alpha =0.8, size = 5, shape = 21) +
      geom_text()
```